# what is the difference in the two way of sending requests by restAssured?

Tags: java, rest-assured

i saw that there is two ways to sending requests to server by restAssured
and want to know the difference between them as

the first way also need the baseURL somewhere

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://google.com";
```

first one :

```
 given("google.com").when().get("/drive").asString()
```

second one :

```
RestAssured.baseURI = "http://google.com";
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();
Response response = httpRequest.get("/drive");
String responseBody = response.asString();
```

so what is the benefit of the first way?
also it is good to mention that each request has to sent with different URL as each one has the .get by her self

also i would like to know how to send cookies in both ways with the request?

Comment: "also it is good to mention that each request has to sent with different URL as each one has the .get by her self"
Could you explain this part a bit more?

Comment: the get is only using the prefix, so the base url most be somewhere at the start in both of the was, am i right? just the using of the methods is different

Comment: Try it without "google.com" in given part. Since you already defined baseUri, it should most probably work without passing it in given() as parameter.
Let me know of the result.

Comment: yes it works, i know it works so in both ways you must define the baseURL first? cause at the documentation at the restAssure website i didn't saw it

Answer (score 0):

Benefit of the first way is using [given when then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given-When-Then) notation, style of representing tests. This makes your tests more readable and is part of BDD ([behavioral driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development))
If you added "then" part instead of asString() you could have done the assertions in a single line.
To add cookies in the first case adding cookie after given would be sufficient like this: given().cookie("my_cookie_name", "my_cookie_value")... etc.
In case two, you would just set cookie on a httpRequest.
More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-header-cookie-parameter).

Comment: so at the second way you must send first the line

    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://google.com";

and then start with all the given etc...?

about the cookies,
at the first way it will look something like(you must know the exact details of the cookie):

    given().cookie(myCookie).when().get("/users/eugenp").then().statusCode(200);

at the second way it is not written there, only the cookie builder?

Comment: If you set basUri you don't have to pass full uri to the get() method, just path.
Regarding cookies, as bhusak said, you are using same classes and methods, cookie should be applicable to Request specification object that you created.
Something like this `RestAssured.requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder().addCookie("my-cookie", "mycookievalue").build();`

Comment: so it will be something like:


     RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given(); 
     Response response = httpRequest.get("/drive");

here i need again to declaire on  requestSpecification ?

     RestAssured.requestSpecification = new 
     RequestSpecBuilder().addCookie("my-cookie", "mycookievalue").build();

Comment: maybe you can attach example how to send cookie after these
RestAssured.baseURI = "www.example.com";      
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given(); 
Response response = httpRequest.get("/test"); 
RestAssured.requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder().addCookie("my cookie","mycookievalue").build();

or i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference cause you are using same class and method. Import for first example will be:

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
```

Import for second will be:

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
```

And for both examples you can do this:

```
RestAssured.baseUri = "http://www.example.com";
//Example 1
RestAssured.given().when().get().then().statusCode(200);
//Example 2
given().when().get().then().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: at the second one(at the example) you must send each time the full URL while in the first one 

     RestAssured.baseURI = "google"; 
     RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given();  
     Response response = httpRequest.get("/drive"); 

so each time only the      Response response = httpRequest.get("/drive"); 
will changed according to your path

Comment: @timothy RestAssured.baseUri is a static variable. Once you changed it value it will be globally applied to all requests unless you manually change it while constructing request specification. I've updated the answer with better example

Comment: thank you for update, it looks the same but the difference will be when doing like so(and these is the long way):

RestAssured.baseUri = "http://www.example.com";
Response response = httpRequest.get("/extra"); 
System.out.println("Response Body is => "+response.asString());